# multiple entries in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, swift

I have a PHP script which adds an unique email to a mysql data base. The PHP script is:

```
<?php
    try {
          $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ourdatabase', 'shyam', 'mypassword');
          $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit();
    }

    try {
          $email=$_POST['email'];
          $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email LIKE '$email'";
          $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
          exit();
    }

    if ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $resturant[] = array('status' => "userexists");
        echo json_encode($resturant);
        exit();
    } else { 
        try {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET
               email = :mailaddress,
               password = :password,
               tagline = :tagline';

            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':mailaddress', $_POST['email']);
            $s->bindValue(':password', $_POST['password']);
            $s->bindValue(':tagline', $_POST['tagline']);
            $s->execute();
            exit();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
             exit();
        }
    } 
   ?>
```

I am accessing this script from a swift file :

```
@IBAction func registerClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = "email=\(email.text!) & password=\(password.text!) & tagline=\(tagline.text!)"
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    for index in 1...10{
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest (request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in })

    task.resume()
    }

    }
```

But multiple entries are added in the database:

databse screen shot

[image]

I ran the loop to check if many users try to register with the same email at the same time. 
How can I run only one instance of this PHP script and let others be in queue. Pls help as I am stuck here.

Comment: Have you tried running a `COUNT()` statement first? Also you are using PDO and you are not using bind to safe-guard against injection `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE email LIKE '$email'";`

Comment: Thanks noted...will include it in php file

Comment: how can I incorporate count() here

Comment: `"SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE email = :email"` - Then fetch the array and you will be left with `$array['count']` which will give you the number.

Comment: Also don't use `LIKE`, use `=`. That will help narrow it down. Also, do the suggestions that @AlexeySoshin has suggested. That will also make it less likely to return a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to simply add UNIQUE on email:

```
alter table users add unique (email)
```

That will help you avoid race conditions.
You're also not handling mixed case scenarios, and not trimming the emails, which you should do.

Comment: I have added the above but rows are skipped while adding same email

Comment: That's because your insert now throws an exception, and you're silently catching it. Check the exception for proper code (893 for unique constraint violation), then return proper HTTP response (409 Conflict for example).